# Elasticsearch compare field data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem. and I have a two field in elasticsearch mapping.I want to compare two field data and want to list the result 1 returns. How can I do this?

```
     {
        "query": {
           "bool": {
              "must": {
                 "range": {
                    "price": {
                       "gt": 100
                    }
                 }
              },
              "filter": {
                 "script": {
                    "script": "doc['departureDate'].value-doc['returnDate'].value==1"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please add the code you have attempted.

Comment: Code updated now